# python input() not printing to screen when piping to another command

Tags: python, shell, io-redirection, getpass

I have a simple python program that is using input to get a username and password, ie:

```
from getpass import getpass

username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass()
```

When i run the program and pipe to wc, the username prompt does not print. It takes input, and then the getpass prompt does print the passowrd prompt.

```
./example.py  | wc -l
sdfsdfsf # Not seeing the "Username: " prompt.
Password:
1
```

I've done some searches. I cannot find out why this is not printing. I am assuming it has to do with redirection or buffers, but I am not sure. Basically, trying to see if there is a way around this.

Comment: I changed the tags; this has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: @9769953 Of course it does.

Comment: does the code snippet you have provided is exactly the same to your source code? The provided code should generate error.

Comment: @Barmar I could write a C program showing the same issue; where is this Python specific?

Comment: @9769953 C doesn't have a built-in function that displays a prompt and asks for input, for which you need to override where it writes the prompt.

Comment: See the answers at the duplicate question, the solutions are very python-specific.

Comment: `input` does something more complicated than just unconditionally writing to standard output. If you redirect only standard error, for example, the prompt is written to standard error. I don't know what the rationale for that is.

Comment: Mind, it's poor form that Python's `input()` isn't using stderr to prompt (POSIX specifies stderr as the right place for "diagnostic" content, and a prompt telling the operator that the program is at a place in its execution where it's ready for input is closer to that than it is to output proper; similarly, common shells -- bash &c -- prompt on stderr), but that bad decision has been in place too long to fix now.